# VTK6 - transform vtkPolyData without pipeline

Tags: c++, vtk

I am trying to use transform a vtkPolyData object by using vtkTransform.
However, the tutorials I found are using pipeline, for example: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Filters/TransformPolyData

However, I am using VTK 6.1 which has removed thge GetOutputPort method for stand-alone data object as mentioned here:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput

I have tried to replace the line:

```
transformFilter->SetInputConnection()
```

with

```
transformFilter->SetInputData(polydata_object);
```

Unfortunately, the data was not read properly (as the pipeline was not set correctly?)

Do you know how to correctly transform a stand-alone vtkPolyData without using pipeline in VTK6?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GetOutputPort was never a method on a data-object. It was always a method on vtkAlgorithm and it still is present on vtkAlgorithm (and subclasses). Where is the polydata_object coming from? If it's an output of a reader, you have two options:

```
// update the reader to ensure it executes and reads data.
reader->UpdatePipeline()

// now you can get access to the data object.
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> data = vtkPolyData::SafeDownCast(reader->GetOutputDataObject(0));

// pass that to the transform filter.
transformFilter->SetInputData(data.GetPointer());
transformFilter->Update();
```

Second option is to simply connect the pipeline:

```
transformFilter->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
```

The key is to ensure that the data is updated/reader before passing it to the transform filter, when not using the pipeline.

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, thanks for your answer. As I am new to VTK, can you tell me what's the difference for data.GetPointer() or just use data? I think both work in my case.

Comment: This is very well explained at http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/SmartPointers (see Passing a Smart Pointer to a function)

Comment: Hi JohnnyQ, if I understand the article correctly, I think there is no difference. As in the case, data is a smart pointer while data.GetPointer() return the raw pointer to the object.

Comment: Yup, in this case, you could have just as easily passed data. It's mostly a style thing, in this case.